# Displaying a absolute positioned div (with width more than parent) on hover of parent going behind next sibling of parent in angular application

Tags: html, css, angular, hover

I have three divs and each div has two child elements and on hover of first child, the second child (hidden & absolute positioned) should be displayed. This might look simple. But since the second child element is absolute positioned, it is going behind the next sibling of the parent element.

[image]

I've tried in all ways like adding z-index dynamically. But no show. I want to make it using only CSS.

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
 }
 .div{
  margin: 0em 1em;
  position: relative;
 }
 .divIn{
  width: 190px;
  height: 260px;
  background: red;
 }
 .divHover{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  bottom: 2em;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
 }
 .divIn:hover ~ .divHover, .divHover:hover{
  display: block;
 }
 .clearfix{
  clear: both;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div">
   <div class="divIn"></div>
   <div class="divHover"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
   <div class="divIn"></div>
   <div class="divHover"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
   <div class="divIn"></div>
   <div class="divHover"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
```

When first element is hovered, hidden second element should be displayed, but it should not go behind the next sibling of parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting the solution as the second child of parent div being on top of next sibling of parent add z-index to class "divHover".

.divHover {z-index: 9;}

Comment: thanks. it worked in static html with n number of divs  but not working in angular 

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding this to the CSS:

```
.div:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 3;
}
.div:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
}
.div:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

### Explanation:

Normally, elements stack in the order that they appear in the DOM (the lowest one down at the same hierarchy level appears on top), so the second `.div` is on top of the first. That's the reason `.div`s go behind their next siblings.

When you set the `z-index` for the child `.divHover` of the first `.div` to a higher value, it's *still* a child of the first `.div` which is below the second `.div`, so your desired effect won't happen.

To solve it you need to position the first `.div` on top of the second. Check the examples here [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

Comment: The divs are actually dynamic. It's an angular application. So we can't write nth-child in css for dynamically generated divs. Hence can't fix with your answer @MoaazBhnas

Comment: Sorry that my answer didn't help. Include this in the question to get more suitable answers. Good luck :D

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to give each dynamically generated `.div` a lower `z-index` value (-1, -2, -3 ... @MohanSaginala)